# Clickable images instead of dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, forms

I have got an array like:

```
    'impact' => array(
        'name' => 'Impact',
        'import' => '',
        'css' => "font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;",
        'image' => 'impact.png'         
    ),
    'palatino-linotype' => array(
        'name' => 'Palatino Linotype',
        'import' => '',
        'css' => "font-family: 'Palatino Linotype', 'Book Antiqua', Palatino, serif;",
        'image' => 'palatino-linotype.png'          
    ),
```

And a dropdown menu like:

```
        <select name="my-options[primary-font]">
        <?php foreach( $fonts as $font_key => $font ): ?>
            <option <?php selected( $font_key == $current_font ); ?> value="<?php echo $font_key; ?>"><?php echo $font['name']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
```

I like to use the images from the array instead of the dropdown menu. So when you click an image the font gets selected. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi Maaerten, were you able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can have one hidden input field and whenever user clicks the image you set the value of hidden input to the font key with JavaScript.